# How to fix "POST http://localhost:9001/demos/dashboard/upload.php 401 (Unauthorized)" in my server

Tags: javascript, php

Im getting a problem when saving a recorded file on the server. The download file is working well but the problem is when uploading the file.    The actual result on the console is

> :POST http://localhost:9001/demos/dashboard/upload.php 401
>   (Unauthorized (anonymous) @ app.js:153 app.js:147 Server returned: 
>   401 Unauthorized: \demos\dashboard\upload.php

```
var upload = document.createElement('a');   upload.href="#";
    upload.innerHTML = "Upload";    upload.addEventListener("click",
 function(){
          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload=function(e) {
              if(this.readyState == 4) {
                  console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
              }
          };
          var fd=new FormData();
          fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
          xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
          xhr.send(fd);     });     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "));  //add a space in between    li.appendChild(upload);  
   //add the upload link to li
```

```
<div id="div001">
        <div id="controls">
     <button class="btn002" id="recordButton">Record</button>
     <button class="btn002" id="pauseButton" disabled>Pause</button>
     <button class="btn002" id="stopButton" disabled>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div id="formats">Start</div>
    <h3>Recordings</h3>
    <ol id="recordingsList"></ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Obviously, your server does require some sort of authentication, which you are not providing.

Comment: The problem occurs at xhr.send(fd);

Comment: Can you clarify your answer a little bit because it works well on http://localhost/RTC/recording/recordmp3.html

Comment: No, the problem does not occur on `xhr.send()` it does occur on your server because you don't provide all necessary information. I don't know what server app you are accessing, but the POST on `upload.php` requires an authentication and that's what the server is telling you. Without telling us, what server you are accessing, nobody will be able to help you beyond telling you to look into the servers documentation

Comment: ok thanks now i understand your point. Before I was using xampp but for the localhot:9001 im using the node server.js